# Can we update the Model properties in MVC view, without a post back or Ajax call? (ASP.Net MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Just wondering if we can update the model properties in the view inside the server tags, then is it possible to update them inside the Java script function, after the user enters the input.

This code is working fine & with the help of model binding, I am able to retrieve the below hardcoded information in the Dialog controller.  "(in CallingModalDialogView2 action method)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.empname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.salary, new { @class = "homeSearchBy" })

 @{ MvcApp3.Models.employee emp = new MvcApp3.Models.employee();
    emp.empid = 12121;     //Hard coded some information 
    emp.empname = "Biki";
    emp.empid = 23;
    emp.salary = 111111111;
  }


@Html.MyFramework().Button("ok", Url.Action("CallingModalDialogView2", "Dialog", emp), "title1", "OK")
```

But when I am trying to put some information in the text box & assign them to the model properties, its not working. Am I doing something wrong or this is not allowed in MVC?

Comment: My intention here is to update the model & on next button click pass the updated model to a pop up (may be a partial page) without any post back. Once the user enters some more data in that page the final button click should do a ajax post & pass all the information that user has entered in main page as well as in pop up.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer for your question: No

Razor code is all rendered on the server side. When you see the page in the browser, the server side operation has finished.

Your Model:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.empname)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.salary, new { @class = "homeSearchBy" })

@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.empid )
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.empname )
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.salary )
```

or:

```
@Html.Hidden("empid", 1212 )
@Html.Hidden("empname", "Biki" )
@Html.Hidden("salary", 100000 )
```

then:

```
<input type="button" id="change-button" value="change" />
```

with JQuery changing data is very easy:

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
  $("#change-button").click(function(){
    $("#empid").val(12);
    $("#empname").val("Morteza");

    // submit form without ajax
    $("form").submit(); 

    // submit form with ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: "Address of your action method",
      type: "Post", // "Get"
      data:  $("form").serialize(),
      success: function(){
        //...
      }
    });        
  });
});
</script>
```

i am using this solution in many project and work fine for me!

Comment: Then how can these information gets updated in the view itself?            @{ MvcApp3.Models.employee emp = new MvcApp3.Models.employee();
    emp.empid = 12121;     //Hard coded some information 
    emp.empname = "Biki";
    emp.empid = 23;
    emp.salary = 111111111;
  }

Comment: if you want change data client side, you must use client side element such as <input type="hidden" id="id">. then change values by javascript or JQuery.

Comment: thats what I ve tried, but found that it could not update my model. Can u post the sample if u ve tried it out & its working fine?